# Align text on center of screen

Tags: html, css

Why is this not working?

I have this:

```
<div class="center">
  <div class="line">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    text2
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    text3
  </div>
</div>
```

in css:

```css
.line {
    display: inline-Block;
    width: 150px;
}

.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Why isn't `.center` css working? I want it to be in center of my screen but it puts it on left corner.

Comment: margin: 0 auto does not center the text, it centers that div inside it's parent container

Comment: Use jQuery `$('selector').css('text-align', 'center');` <---- Just kidding, don't ask such basic questions, please use Google for god sake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `center` div takes up the full width of the page. The `line` divs are aligned to the left of the `center` div. If you specify a width for the `center` div, it will appear in the center of the page. I made an example for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/LGuAq/
If you remove the `width: 470px;` line, you'll see what's going on. I added a black div border just to show where each div is and how big it is.

Answer (score 1):

Change `.center` to this:

```
.center {
     text-align: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9VNtR/)

Comment: Not text, I need to align on center hole "line" css, I have input fields in line, i have only put text for example...

Answer (score 1):

Give .center a width, or it assumes 100% and there is no margin to be had:

```
.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don´t you try this:

```
.line {
text-align:center;
display: inline-Block;
width: 150px;
}

.center{ 
display: inline-block;
}
```